# Parse Author from Word 97-2003 document without Word in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, .doc

I need to parse the "author"-property from a word document (97-2003). Preferably without using the Word COM-Object. I'am doing that same thing for .docx-documents by using the docx-nuget, but it seems that it can't handle the old .doc format.

I tried Spire.Doc but the free version is to limited (can't open large documents) and the paid version is a bit too expensive for me.

Is it possible at all to do this? And if so, how do I open and parse the "author"-property?

Answer (score -1):

We used dsoFile.dll to both read and write properties in doc-files.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/224351

Add reference to Interop.DSOFile

```
using DSOFile;
public static string GetAuthorFromFile(string filename)
{
 var test = new OleDocumentProperties();
 test.Open(filename, true, DSOFile.dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionDefault);
 return test.SummaryProperties.Author;
}
```

See:
[Why dsofile.dll still need Office Installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051543/why-dsofile-dll-still-need-office-installation)

As an alternative you could use:
http://officefileproperties.codeplex.com/
but then you will also need to include Office Interop with your application.